# Build a regular pattern with fixed colors

Tags: arrays, algorithm, distribution

I have groups of coloured coins. Each group has a number of coins which may or may not be the same as others.

I want to put all the coins in an array, with a constraint : I want the distribution to be as regular as possible. This will then be used to draw a bigger line with the exact ratio of every colour.

Example 1:

- 2 Black
- 2 White
- 1 Red

Result : B W R B W

Example 2:

- 49 Black
- 49 White
- 2 Red

Result : (BW)x12 R (BW)x25 R (BW)x12

The result is a succession of Black and White, with the two Red coins beeing at positions ~25 and ~75 (meaning they are distant of 50).

Example 3:

- 4 Black
- 4 White
- 1 Red
- 1 Green

Result : BWRBWBGWBW

The Green and Red coins are "far" from each other as well.

NB: The problem has already been "reduced" (ie never 50 black and 50 white coins : This case has been simplified to 2 coins : 1 black and one white).

Comment: are the black and white always the same quantity, and we need to intersperse the other ones?

Comment: "Regular" seems like a subjective value to me. For example, I think the most regular pattern for 49 black 49 white 2 red would be (BW)x33 R (BW)x32 R (BW)x33. Can you explain why your output is more regular than mine? If so, that will help you define what "regular" really means, in a way the computer can understand.

Comment: I will build a bigger list by repeating the "regular" pattern. Thus, the last 33 (BW) will be followed by the first series, making 66 consecutive (BW).

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to shuffle all of them and just put them randomly in the array - with enough coins this will tend to be regular.

Another way would be to go over the coins from the smallest group to the largest and spread the coins as equally as possible. Let's look at the 2nd example: You take the reds and put them once every `100 / 2 = 50` places:

```
R _ _ _ ... R _ _ _ ... _ _ _
```

Then you take the whites and put it in every `(100 - 2) / 49 = 2` index starting from the 1st index:

```
R W _ W _ ... R W _ W _ ... _ W _
```

And so on with the black every `(100 - 2 - 49) / 49 = 1` index:

```
R W B W B ... R W B W B ... B W B
```

Ok... now I see that the OP also asked for the reds and greens to be as far as possible in the 3rd example, so to achieve that we will have to slightly change the algorithm. we will have to order the groups according to their sizes and iterating between the colors when spreading them. so in the 3rd examples the first group is of size 2 and consists of the reds and greens.